# Laminas-Cache 2.13 PHP8 upgrade

Tags: composer-php, upgrade, php-8, laminas

I've been running into some problems upgrading my server from PHP7.3 to PHP8.0, so I figured I'd list what I've found and ask if anyone else has a better solution.

**The Problem I'm running into:** I've got a PHP Laminas application that uses the laminas/laminas-cache package in composer.json; the problem is that it has several dependancies that are NOT compatible with PHP8 (also, several of the dependencies are abandoned), so I get errors like this:

```
- laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-apc[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.1] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-cache 2.13.0 requires laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-apc ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-apc[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
- Root composer.json requires laminas/laminas-cache ^2.13 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-cache[2.13.0].
```

It looks like laminas/laminas-cache 3.0 will solve a bunch of the dependency problems, but it's still in a Dev state, so it's considered too unstable for my production environment. Which means that I've got to use laminas/laminas-cache 2.13.

**How to fix it:** It took me a while to find this documentation, but as far as I can tell you're supposed to pick-and-choose which dependencies you want to ignore by putting them in a Replace section:

https://github.com/laminas/laminas-cache/issues/88

And here is the standard list of packages to "replace:"

```
"replace": {
    "laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-apc": "*",
    "laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-dba": "*",
    "laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-mongodb": "*",
    "laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-wincache": "*",
    "laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-xcache": "*",
    "laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-zend-server": "*"
},
```

Once I've copy/pasted that section into composer.json it allows me to successfully run `composer update` without it throwing a fit, but I'm not a huge fan of having a bunch of packages replaced with with "*" version wildcard.

**So... my question is:** Is there a better a way to do this, or have I stumbled onto the best solution until laminas/laminas-cache 3.0 is complete?

Comment: If this is the documented way of using it, do it :)

Comment: Sounds good! I'm still pretty new to Composer stuff, so I wanted a 2nd opinion. Thanks for the help!